# Fast Fourier Transform with only Hermitian-symmetric output using R

Tags: r, python, fourier-transform

I am trying to translate this [gravitational wave signal processing tutorial](https://losc.ligo.org/s/events/GW150914/GW150914_tutorial.html) from Python to R, which I am much more familiar with. I believe I am having problems getting it to work due the whitening step which uses this function:

> Compute the one-dimensional discrete Fourier Transform for real input.
>
> This function computes the one-dimensional n-point discrete Fourier
>   Transform (DFT) of a real-valued array by means of an efficient
>   algorithm called the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).
>
> [...]
>
> When the DFT is computed for purely real input, the output is
>   Hermitian-symmetric, i.e. the negative frequency terms are just the
>   complex conjugates of the corresponding positive-frequency terms, and
>   the negative-frequency terms are therefore redundant. This function
>   does not compute the negative frequency terms, and the length of the
>   transformed axis of the output is therefore n//2 + 1.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html

I'm not very familiar with this process, but thought I figured out it meant only remove the results where the real and imaginary parts have opposite signs and thus tried to implement it this way in R:

```
hf=fft(dat)
rem=which((Re(hf)>0 & Im(hf)<0)|(Re(hf)<0 & Im(hf)>0))
hf=hf[-rem]
```

Since I still don't get the same final result I suspect I am wrong. Is there an easy way to implement this or a package available that performs the same function (and also the inverse)?

**Edit:**

Yes, the above is surely wrong. That misbelief arose due to the specific set of numbers I tried earlier. I tried again using the numpy function and see these results:

**Python:**

```
    strain=[12,23,432,19,13,45,22,148,2]
    hf1 = np.fft.rfft(strain)
    hf2 = np.fft.fft(strain)

>>> hf1
array([ 716.00000000  +0.j        ,   56.86488212-279.64122086j,
       -504.74993791-140.98196324j, -278.50000000+255.47749412j,
        422.38505579+146.45348626j])
>>> hf2
array([ 716.00000000  +0.j        ,   56.86488212-279.64122086j,
       -504.74993791-140.98196324j, -278.50000000+255.47749412j,
        422.38505579+146.45348626j,  422.38505579-146.45348626j,
       -278.50000000-255.47749412j, -504.74993791+140.98196324j,
         56.86488212+279.64122086j])
```

**R:**

```
strain=c(12,23,432,19,13,45,22,148,2)
> fft(strain)
[1]  716.0000+  0.0000i   56.8649-279.6412i -504.7499-140.9820i
[4] -278.5000+255.4775i  422.3851+146.4535i  422.3851-146.4535i
[7] -278.5000-255.4775i -504.7499+140.9820i   56.8649+279.6412i
```

The R fft function gives the same output as seen using np.fft.fft.